# how do you add a named range to worksheet using php pear spreadsheet excel writer

Tags: php, excel, pear

Is it posible using Excel_spreadsheet_writer to create a name such as

```
$workbook  = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer();
$worksheet = &$workbook->addWorksheet('CheckNames');

$worksheet->writeName(0, 0, 'AnswerToEverythig', '42');

$worksheet->write(0, 1, 'Double =');

$worksheet->writeFormula(0, 2, '=AnswerToEverythig * 2');

$workbook->send('CheckNames.xls');
$workbook->close();
```

and dispay 84 in cell C1

As recommended by cypher I've tried PHPExcel but now get Internal Server Error on the following

```
$prices_sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(4, $row, '=IF(Round_Up=0,  (C'.$row.'+D'.$row.'),  0.01  )');
```

changing the formula to

```
'=IF(0=0,  (C'.$row.'+D'.$row.'),  0.01  )'
```

stops the error.

Therefore PHPExcel has problems resolving formulas using named ranges.

Found This
http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=209472

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how about `SpreadSheetExcelWriter`, but it certainly can be done with [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/). I've been using `PHPExcel` for a long time and I can only recommend it.

Comment: Not a solution to the problem but PHPExcel seems to be the better choice